# Developing Themes on WordPress, Looking for Excellent Tutorials

Tags: plugin-development, themes, customization

I am a beginner at WordPress. I know html, asp, a little PHP and I'm familiar with WordPress. I want to be an WordPress expert. So far I know WordPress involves designing themes, making plugins and customized websites. Please let me know of any other things I need to do.
Please provide links of some excellent tutorials( free to access, not want to buy) ..to get started with WordPress from beginner to expert.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to learn wordpress is for me the site & the book from http://digwp.com/

To learn how to build your own themes you might want to look at http://www.sitepoint.com/books/wordpress1/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people start right in with modifying the twenty ten theme that comes with WordPress.... so let me start right out by pointing out that should never be done.
http://go.rvoodoo.com/WPchild
is my write-up about child themes. Child themes are used to modify existing themes. They are important for the twenty ten theme because twenty ten gets upgraded when WordPress does, so if you modify twenty ten without using a child theme, your changes will get lost. Other themes also frequently get upgraded, so same point, if the theme gets upgraded and you didn't use a child theme, you will lose your changes. So unless making your own new theme, always consider a child theme.

Other than that, maybe check out my site at

http://voodoopress.com

A lot of neat tips and tricks for themes there (especially child themes) to get you started

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some of the sites which i used. Hope you find it useful. These contains tutorials as simple as possible.

- https://www.taniarascia.com/tutorials/#wordpress
- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/theme-development/
- https://code.tutsplus.com/series/developing-your-first-wordpress-theme--wp-33845